# Is it viable to have a session cookie with SameSite=Lax and another static SameSite=strict cookie to make the Lax cookie more secure?

Tags: security, web, cookies

I have a Rails web application and for most routes I would like the session cookie to be protected via `SameSite=strict`. But sometimes, like for example for oauth callbacks, I would like it to behave like `SameSite=lax`. While thinking about the problem I noticed that Google sets their session cookie to `lax` in Gmail but seems to keep a `strict` cookie around with a static value inside. That made me wonder whether I could do this and have some application code that checks if the strict cookie is available and use that information to decide whether my lax cookie is safe. That would allow me to opt out of `strict` for the oauth callback allowing me to keep the session around there by turning off this check for that route.

For full context, I want to remember on which page the user started the sign in/sign up process to redirect them back there later.

My question is whether I am missing some security problem and also if this overly complicated and there is a simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure out how to do this? I'm facing the same issue currently.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that SameSite is used for protecting csrf attacks. If another page redirects to your page, your page should not change the password for example. For sensitive actions, you should check for a presence of the strict cookie. Use of lax cookie is insecure when other site can redirect a user to trick the user into doing unwanted actions.

Lax cookie is pretty much most have for login functionality. When some other website redirects to your site, you will need the lax cookie to verify the user login state (otherwise when they first load the page they won't send any cookie on the first request).

Note that lax cookie doesn't make your cookie less safe, but rather, malicious website might take advantage of the cookie if they redirect the user to a website that use lax cookie.

As long as any sensitive action checks for a presence of strict cookie and valid session, usage of lax cookie is generally safe.